# Grouping a sequence into two sets, then printing from first set based on num of elements in second set using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

The quick explanation of the problem: I have a list of items in a specific order that I group by into 2 lists, left and right. Now, let's say I want to print 10 elements, and the caveat is that I want to print as many as I can from the right list (i.e. if this list has 10 elements, then great all of them from this list), but if I fall short, I want to print from the left list, but those items that are closest to the right list.

One idea I had was this ... don't know if we can write shorter, terser code.

```
var totalToPrint = 10
var listA,listB = originalList group by where some condition that is bool and hence two lists
var interimRightList = listB.Take(totalToPrint);
var myfinallist = listA.Skip(listA.length - interimRightList.Count()) + interimRightList;
```

This is really all my brain could come up with, if you know an easier way of doing this please let me know. I still have to aactually write the real C# code for this ... i'm making this sound simple (maybe it is), but dunno...

Here's the formal description:

Given an enumeration, for example: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}

I want to group these into two sets, A and B … a function will be provided to decide which set they belong to. For simplicity, let’s assume it’s putting into an Odd set and an Even set, given the above sequence.

Now, I want to output as many items from set B (let’s say X number of items), and then output as many items from set A (let’s say Y number of items), such that X + Y = Z and no more. In other words, if Z is 10, and X is 10, then we pick nothing from list A. Similarly if Z is 5, and X is 10, then we pick 5 elements from B, and none from A.

Also, this should be stable, i.e. the ordering should not be changed.

A more complete example 

{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12} – let’s assume our set dividing function is any element that is less than 11, goes into A, otherwise goes into B. And let’s say we have to print 3 elements. Therefore we’ll pick {11, 12} from B, and then pick {10} from  A. and print in order … so that will print 10, 11, 12.

Here's how this looks in normal code:

```
int remaining = 10;
int a = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < listB.Count() && remaining > -1; ++i, ++a, remaining--)
{
   // don't print(listB[i]); i.e do nothing
}

if (remaining > 0)
{
    for (int i = listA.length - remaining; i < listA.length; ++i)
    {
        print(listA[i]);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < a; ++i)
{
     print(listB[i]);
}
```

FYI, this may sound like but is not an interview question, it's a real world problem.

Comment: What is your business rule for `but those items that are closest to the right list.`? eg What is "closest" in the example where odd goes into A and even goes into B?

Comment: left to right, i.e. if i have, 1, 2, 3 in the left list, and 4, 5, 6 in the right list ... and I need to print 5 items ... they would be 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ... does that help?

Comment: yes - Hightechrider's solution does that although I had to fiddle the syntax to get it working :)

Answer (score 1):

Very hard to follow your question.  You should perhaps just start with listA and listB and explain what you really want to get from them.  I think you are asking for:

```
var result = (listA.Reverse().Take(Y).Concat(listB.Reverse())).Take(Z).Reverse();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm at a loss as to what you're trying to do...  Nonetheless, I will take a stab at it using your odds and even example.  I will write my example as a standard C# console application.

There is no way to my knowledge to split an enumerable using LINQ.  Thus, my example will use two separate lambda expressions to split the IEnumerable into to different groups.  I then take the specified number of items from A assign to AB.  After this, I union the remainder (if any) of the specified number from B into AB.  The last section iterates through and prints each into a CSV string.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] numArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

        OddsAndEvens(7, numArray);
        OddsAndEvens(4, numArray);
    }

    public static void OddsAndEvens(int numToPrint, int[] array)
    {
        var a = array.Where(n => n % 2 == 0); // evens
        var b = array.Where(n => !(n % 2 == 0)); // not evens, thus odds
        var ab = a.Take(numToPrint);
        ab = ab.Union(b.Take(numToPrint - ab.Count()));

        foreach (int i in ab)
        {
            Console.Write(i + ", ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any enter to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Note: A better method may be to cast the array to a string, and then use string.Join to create a CSV, but I've left this part out to avoid more confusion.